# Removing fractions without a particular variable

Tags: performance-tuning, algebraic-manipulation

As a very minimal example, consider a sum of fractions such as:

$A=\frac{a}{s_{123}bc}+\frac{d}{e}$

In practice, I have many hundreds of thousands of these fractions generated from a recursion relation. My desired result comes around from the prescription in my theory, where I am required to multiply through by $s_{123}$ and then take $s_{123}\to 0$. Upon replicating in MMA, I use a code similar to:

```
A*s[1,2,3]//Expand
%/.{s[1,2,3]->0}
```

This `Expand` is necessary since by simply multiplying `A` by the relevant factor, MMA will first interpret it as $s_{123} \big (\frac{a}{s_{123}bc}+\frac{d}{e}\big)$. I think this is what is slowing my code down substantially, and crashes MMA due to a lack of memory.

To get around this, I have had a few ideas;

1. Use something like `DeleteCase` as a simple method (or something perhaps similar to [Filter out all terms not involving a given variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128188/filter-out-all-terms-not-involving-a-given-variable) which might be a bit overkill for my needs) to delete all terms **not** involving $s_{123}$, and then set the remaining factors of it in the leftover terms to 1.
2. Instead of using `Expand`, define a new function which brings common factors inside to each fraction.

Which of these, alongside any other methods, would you suggest? How could I go about implementing them? I think 2 would be easier to do, but at this point, I am needing efficiency in my code on such a large scale.

Comment: You might find that working with a `List` of terms is better (e.g. effectively `List@@A`) than working with a sum of terms.  Presumably `Expand` is comparing a large number of terms, looking for common subexpressions.

Comment: I would have thought `Cancel[]` would work better here than `Expand[]`.

Comment: `Cancel` actually crashes my code in this case. It simply runs out of memory on my laptop, but nonetheless; `Expand` was my first thought, and did the trick at the time when efficiency wasn't as important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pick out only those terms in `A` that contain exactly one `s123` in the denominator:

```
A = a/(s123 b c) + d/e;

Select[A, Exponent[#, s123] == -1 &] /. s123 -> 1
```

> a/(b c)

or with pattern matching using a [`Default`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Default.html) pattern (*):

```
Total[Cases[A, _./s123, {1}]] /. s123 -> 1
```

> a/(b c)

or with pattern-based case deletion:

```
DeleteCases[A, Except[_./s123]] /. s123 -> 1
```

> a/(b c)

You'll have to check what's fastest in your case.

### Timing comparison

Faking a random input:

```
SeedRandom[1234];
A = Total[Times @@@ ({a, b, c, s}^# & /@ RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {10^4, 4}])];
```

Method 1: `Select` is quite fast:

```
First[T1 = RepeatedTiming[Select[A, Exponent[#, s] == -1 &] /. s -> 1]]
(* 0.042 *)
```

Method 2: `Cases` is very fast:

```
First[T2 = RepeatedTiming[Total[Cases[A, _./s, {1}]] /. s -> 1]]
(* 0.006 *)
```

Method 3: `DeleteCases` is about equally fast, depending on the exact input:

```
First[T3 = RepeatedTiming[DeleteCases[A, Except[_./s]] /. s -> 1]]
(* 0.0081 *)
```

@CarlWoll's method is very slow:

```
First[T4 = RepeatedTiming[SeriesCoefficient[A, {s, 0, -1}]]]
(* 5.12 *)
```

check that the results agree:

```
T1[[2]] == T2[[2]] == T3[[2]] == T4[[2]] // Expand
(* True *)
```

### Footnote

(*) We need a special `Default` pattern for `1/s123` because it does not match the pattern `_/s123`. Why not? The full form of `x/s123` (with anything for `x`) has head `Times`:

```
x/s123 //FullForm
(* Times[Power[s123, -1], x] *)
```

The full form of `1/s123`, on the other hand, has head `Power`:

```
1/s123 //FullForm
(* Power[s123, -1] *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful and informative comment. Only off the top of your head, can you think of any other alternative methods that may be faster which I have not considered before?

Comment: The pattern `(_ : 1)/s` instead of `_/s | 1/s` works.

Comment: I've added `DeleteCases` as another fast method.

Comment: @Somos the default pattern `_./s` works too and looks even simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use [`SeriesCoefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesCoefficient)?

```
A = a/(s123 b c) + d/e;
SeriesCoefficient[A, {s123, 0, -1}]
```

> a/(b c)

Comment: Because it's terribly slow, see my answer.

Comment: In my extended case, it took around 41 seconds, compared to my original method which took around 5. The improvements from Roman both took sub-1 second when applied to the practical case. Thank you for your answer; although it's not quite what I needed in this situation, it serves as a pleasant reminder of the in-built capabilities of MMA.