# Remove specific terms from Mathematica output

Tags: simplifying-expressions, filtering, parametric-functions

I have a very complicated output from Mathematica - which may run to several pages - and I want to keep only some of the terms.

The expression I am working with is a double summation.  It results in (several pages) of output, but many of the terms include variables raised to a power where the power is a function of $n$.  For example:

```
\begin{equation}
a^4b^2(2a^3+a^7-4abc(6a-9)+a^{2n+6}\left(8+9bc-6a^{2n-8}\right))
\end{equation}
```

In my problem, $n$ is very large, such that I want to be able to ignore any individual terms involving this power because they become negligible.  The expression above would become:

```
\begin{equation}
a^4 b^2 (2a^3 + a^7 - 4abc(6a-9) )
\end{equation}
```

Any assistance gratefully received - I have about 5 pages of output to sift through otherwise!

I have looked at this post

[enter link description here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128188/filter-out-all-terms-not-involving-a-given-variable)

and have tried the delete with function suggested, but
it removes all of the terms in the above example.

Here is a small sample of the Mathematica Output I am trying to simplify:

```
((1 - a)^2 (1 - b)^2 (1 - 
 c)^2 (a^(4 + 2 n) (-1 + b^2) (b - c)^2 (-1 + b c) (-1 + c^2) + 
 a^(6 + 2 n) b (-1 + b^2) (b - c)^2 c (-1 + b c) (-1 + c^2) - 
 a^(5 + 2 n) (-1 + b^2) (b - c)^2 (-1 + c^2) (-c + b^2 c + 
    b (-1 + c^2)) + 
 2 a^(2 + n)
   b c (-b c^(5 + n) + b^3 c^(5 + n) + b^(5 + n) c (-1 + c^2) + 
    c^(2 + n) (-1 + c^2) - b^4 c^(2 + n) (-1 + c^2) + 
    b^(2 + n) (-1 + c^4) - b^(4 + n) (-1 + c^4)) + 
 2 a^(6 + n)
   b c (-b c^(1 + n) + b^3 c^(1 + n) + b^(1 + n) c (-1 + c^2) - 
    c^(2 + n) (-1 + c^2) + b^4 c^(2 + n) (-1 + c^2) - 
    b^(2 + n) (-1 + c^4) + b^(4 + n) (-1 + c^4)) + 
 2 a^(5 + 
   n) (-c^(3 + n) - b^2 c^(3 + n) + b^4 c^(3 + n) + 
    b^6 c^(3 + n) + b^(3 + n) (-1 + c^2) (1 + c^2)^2 + 
    b^(6 + n) c (-1 + c^4) - b c^(2 + n) (-1 + c^4) + 
    b^5 c^(2 + n) (-1 + c^4) + b^(2 + n) (c - c^5)) - 
 2 a^(3 + 
   n) (c^(5 + n) + b^2 c^(5 + n) - b^4 c^(5 + n) - b^6 c^(5 + n) -
     b^(5 + n) (-1 + c^2) (1 + c^2)^2 + b^(6 + n) c (-1 + c^4) - 
    b c^(2 + n) (-1 + c^4) + b^5 c^(2 + n) (-1 + c^4) + 
    b^(2 + n) (c - c^5)) + 
 a^3 (-b^(5 + 2 n) (-1 + c^2) (1 + c^2)^2 - 
    2 b^3 (-1 + (a b)^n) (-1 + c^2) (1 + c^2)^2 + 
    b^(4 + 2 n) c (-1 + c^4) + b^(6 + 2 n) c (-1 + c^4) - 
    b c^2 (1 + c^2) (-2 + c^2 + c^(2 + 2 n)) + 
    b^5 (1 + c^2) (1 - 2 c^2 + c^(4 + 2 n)) + 
    c^3 (-2 + c^2 + c^(2 + 2 n) + 2 (a c)^n) - 
    b^6 c (1 + c^(4 + 2 n) + 2 c^2 (-1 + (a c)^n)) + 
    b^2 c (2 - c^4 + c^(4 + 2 n) + 2 c^2 (-1 + (a c)^n)) - 
    b^4 c (-1 + 2 c^4 + c^(4 + 2 n) + 2 c^2 (-1 + (a c)^n))) + 
 a^5 (c^3 - c^(5 + 2 n) + 2 c^5 (a c)^n - 2 b^6 c^5 (a c)^n + 
    b^(4 + 2 n) c (-1 + c^2) - 2 b^(2 + n) c^(3 + n) (-1 + c^2) + 
    2 b^(6 + n) c^(3 + n) (-1 + c^2) + b^(5 + 2 n) (-1 + c^4) - 
    2 b^(3 + n) c^(2 + n) (-1 + c^4) + 
    2 b^(5 + n) c^(2 + n) (-1 + c^4) + 
    b^(6 + 2 n) (c + c^3 - 2 c^5) + 
    b c^2 (-1 + c^2) (1 + c^(2 + 2 n)) + 
    b^3 (1 + c^2) (1 - 2 c^2 + c^(4 + 2 n)) - 
    2 b^5 (-(a b)^n - (1 + (a b)^n) c^2 + (a b)^n c^4 + (a b)^
        n c^6 + c^(6 + 2 n)) + 
    b^4 (c - 2 c^3 + c^(5 + 2 n) - 2 c^5 (a c)^n) + 
    b^2 c (-1 - c^2 + 2 c^4 (1 + (a c)^n))) + 
 a^6 b c (2 b^(4 + n) c^(2 + n) + 2 b^(2 + n) c^(4 + n) - 
    2 (b c)^(4 + n) - b^(4 + 2 n) (-1 + c^2) + 
    b^(5 + 2 n) c (-1 + c^2) - 2 b^5 (a b)^n c (-1 + c^2) + 
    c^2 (-1 + c^(2 + 2 n)) + 
    b^3 c (-1 + c^(4 + 2 n) - 2 c^4 (a c)^n) - 
    b c (-2 + c^2 + c^(4 + 2 n) - 2 c^4 (a c)^n) - 
    b^2 (1 + c^(4 + 2 n) + 2 c^2 (-1 + (b c)^n))) + 
 a^4 (c^2 - 2 c^4 + 2 b^(6 + n) c^(2 + n) + 
    2 b^(5 + n) c^(3 + n) + 2 b^(3 + n) c^(5 + n) + 
    2 b^(2 + n) c^(6 + n) + c^(4 + 2 n) + 
    b^(5 + 2 n) c^3 (-1 + c^2) + b^(4 + 2 n) (1 + c^2 - 2 c^4) + 
    b^(6 + 2 n) c^2 (-1 + c^4) + b c (-2 + c^2 + c^4) - 
    2 b^4 (1 + c^2 - 3 c^4 + c^(4 + 2 n)) + 
    b^6 c^2 (-1 + c^(4 + 2 n) - 2 c^4 (b c)^n) + 
    b^5 (c - 2 c^3 + c^(5 + 2 n) - 2 c^5 (b c)^n) - 
    b^3 c (-1 + 2 c^4 + c^(4 + 2 n) + 2 c^2 (-1 + (b c)^n)) - 
    b^2 (-1 + 2 c^4 + c^6 - c^(4 + 2 n) + c^(6 + 2 n) + 
       2 c^2 (-1 + (b c)^n))) - 
 a^2 (2 b^(6 + n) c^(2 + n) + 2 b^(5 + n) c^(3 + n) + 
    2 b^(3 + n) c^(5 + n) + 2 b^(2 + n) c^(6 + n) + 
    b^(5 + 2 n) (c - c^3) - b^(4 + 2 n) (-1 + c^4) + 
    b^(6 + 2 n) c^2 (-2 + c^2 + c^4) + c^4 (-1 + c^(2 n)) + 
    b c^3 (-2 + c^2 + c^(2 + 2 n)) - 
    2 b^2 c^2 (-3 + (a b)^n - (-1 + (a b)^n) c^2 + c^4 + c^(
       4 + 2 n) + (a c)^n + (b c)^n) + 
    b^6 c^2 (-2 + c^2 + c^(4 + 2 n) - 2 c^4 (b c)^n) + 
    b^4 (-1 + 2 c^4 + c^6 - c^(4 + 2 n) + c^(6 + 2 n) + 
       2 c^2 (-1 + (a c)^n)) - 
    b^3 c (2 - c^4 + c^(4 + 2 n) + 2 c^2 (-1 + (b c)^n)) + 
    b^5 (c + c^3 - 2 c^5 (1 + (b c)^n))) - 
 b^2 c^2 (-b^(2 + 2 n) (-1 + c^2) + b^(3 + 2 n) c (-1 + c^2) + 
    c^2 (-1 + c^(2 n)) - b^2 (1 - 2 c^2 + c^(2 + 2 n)) + 
    b^3 c (-1 + c^(2 + 2 n) + 2 (b c)^n - 2 c^2 (b c)^n) + 
    b c (2 - c^(2 + 2 n) - 2 (b c)^n + c^2 (-1 + 2 (b c)^n))) + 
 a b c (2 b^(2 + n) c^(5 + n) - 2 b^(4 + n) c^(5 + n) + 
    b^(5 + 2 n) c^2 (-1 + c^2) - 
    2 b^(5 + n) c^(2 + n) (-1 + c^2) + b^(4 + 2 n) c (-1 + c^4) + 
    b^3 (-2 + c^2 + c^4) - b^(3 + 2 n) (-2 + c^2 + c^4) + 
    2 c^3 (-1 + c^(2 n)) + b^5 c^2 (-1 + c^(2 + 2 n)) + 
    b^4 c (-1 + c^2 - c^(2 + 2 n) + c^(4 + 2 n) + 2 (b c)^n) - 
    b^2 c (-2 - c^2 + c^4 + c^(2 + 2 n) + c^(4 + 2 n) + 
       2 (b c)^n) + 
    b c^2 (2 - c^(2 + 2 n) - 2 (b c)^n + 
       c^2 (-1 + 2 (b c)^n)))))/((-1 + a^2) (a - b)^2 (-1 + 
 a b) (-1 + b^2) (a - c)^2 (b - c)^2 (-1 + a c) (-1 + b c) (-1 + 
 c^2))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your long expression (call it `expr`) above:

```
expr2 = (expr /. e_^(a_. * n + b_.) :> 0) // Simplify

(* -(((-1 + a) (-1 + b) (-1 + c) (-1 - b c + a^2 b c (1 + b c) + 
       a (-c + b^2 c + b (-1 + c^2))))/((1 + a) (1 + b) (-1 + a b) (1 + 
       c) (-1 + a c) (-1 + b c))) *)
```